# How do I use forEach to turn an array of strings into a single string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, if-statement, foreach

```
/*Your task in this activity is to implement a function called createParagraph that takes an array of strings, and returns a single string containing all the items in the array separated by a space.*/
```

```html
/*Your task in this activity is to implement a function called createParagraph that takes an array of strings, and returns a single string containing all the items in the array separated by a space.*/



//Use forEach to create a single paragraph from a list of words.
// This is a list of words
let words = ['Loops', 'are', 'a', 'great', 'way', 'to', 'find', 'elements', 'in', 'an', 'array'];

// TODO: implement this function to return a string containing all words in a paragraph.
function createParagraph(words) {
  let paragraph = '';
  
  return paragraph.forEach(words);
}

// Prints paragraph to console
console.log(createParagraph(words));

// don't change this line
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = createParagraph;
}
```

Comment: just return `return words.join(' ');`

Comment: Does the lesson require that you use forEach?  If so, then it's words.forEach, and the block appends its param to paragraph

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `forEach` on `strings`. `forEach` is meant to be used with `arrays`

You can make use of [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) here to join an array.

```js
let words = [
  'Loops',
  'are',
  'a',
  'great',
  'way',
  'to',
  'find',
  'elements',
  'in',
  'an',
  'array',
];

function createParagraph(words) {
  return words.join(' ');
}

console.log(createParagraph(words));
```

Comment: This is clearly a homework assignment and meant to teach how to iterate over an array and build the paragraph manually. The requirement is to use `forEach`, and you shouldn't just give the answer away to a student.